# Estimating the probability that a particular batch of ten will include at least a faulty phone

Tags: probability, statistics

> A uk distributor is to import $1000$ mobile phones which will be sold
>   with an insurance package for $£400$ each. They will be sent out to a
>   number of shops in batches of $10$. The distributor noted that, in
>   previous orders from the same manufacturer, $0.5\%$ of the phones were
>   found to be faulty.
>
> a) Estimate the probability that a particular batch of ten will
>   include at least one faulty phone. Be sure to explain your reasoning.

Answer (score 1):

Let us take $p=0.005$ to be the probability that a given phone will be faulty. Then we may use the binomial distribution to understand the probability of drawing $k$ faulty phones from a sample of $n$.

We know that the only situation where we don’t get at least one faulty phone is when every phone is non-faulty, which has a probability of $(1-p)^{10}$. Then the probability of at least one being faulty is $1-(1-p)^{10} \approx 0.04889...$.